# Is there a way to have the UI auto update with a change in a state object in Android just like how react and react native does. But using java

Tags: java, android, redux, observer-pattern

I've been working with React web application development. I enjoy how changing the state object with `setSate()` automatically updates all UI elements subscribed to that state object.

I want to know if the is such auto updating with state changing in Android development with Java programming.

Comment: You will want to look into data binding in terms of what Android offers today. Jetpack Compose has similar capabilities, but that is Kotlin and will not be available in a stable release until 2021 (probably).

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and fix up that last sentence. It's hard to know what you're asking specifically because the wording seems jumbled.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I think that's what I'm looking for. I'll go do more research on it.  I think there is a data binding with Java